# Swift: Extracting value from optional

Tags: swift, conditional-statements

I am trying to get both the largest and the largestKind out of a dictionary of different number sequences.

```
var largest = 0
var largestKind: String?
for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for number in numbers {
        if number > largest {
            largest = number
            if largestKind != kind {
                largestKind = kind
            }
        }
    }
}
largest
largestKind
```

I only want to set largestKind if the previous value of largestKind is not the same one. I know it is almost useless to do this but I'm just trying to get a better feel of Swift. I tried using an if statement with let but I can't get it to work with a condition.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the value from an optional using [Optional Binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_485):

```
for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for number in numbers {
        if number > largest {
            largest = number
            if let oldLargestKind = largestKind {
                if oldLargestKind != kind {
                    largestKind = kind
                }
            }
            else {
                // largestKind was nil
                largestKind = kind
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, it would be cleaner and still work if you just assign it no matter what:

```
for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for number in numbers {
        if number > largest {
            largest = number
            largestKind = kind
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, if you really want to dive into Swift, here is another implementation:

```
let (largest, largestKind) = reduce(interestingNumbers, (num: 0, kind: nil)) {
    (largest: (num: Int, kind: String?), next: (kind: String, numbers: [Int])) in

    func maxNumInArray(array: [Int]) -> Int {
        return array.reduce(0, combine: max)
    }

    var localLargest = maxNumInArray(next.numbers)
    return localLargest > largest.num ? (localLargest, next.kind) : largest
}
```

This is actually worse from an understandability perspective, but it shows off some more advanced features in Swift:

- Nested functions
- Functional programming features like "reduce" that takes a sequence and reduces it down to a single value by combining each element
- [Tuples](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_476) with named parameters
- Returning multiple values from a function
- Ternary operator

---

**Edit:** To get access to the unwrapped value of largestKind at the end:

```
if let actualLargestKind = largestKind {
    // In here you have access to the value stored in
    // largestKind under the name of actualLargestKind
    doSomethingWithTheLargestKind(actualLargestKind)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a very clear and complete explanation.

Comment: I copied and pasted the last implementation into my swift playground and it didn't compile. Could you please verify that the last implementation is correct?

Comment: I did for how I assume interestingNumbers is defined. How is it defined?

Comment: Another question: I am still getting {Some "Square"}. How can I extract the value from it?

Comment: @Tomasero same as in my first loop: `if let actualKind = largestKind { // do something with actualKind }`

Comment: I understand that the way of extracting it is using "let".
Nevertheless, I am still getting {Some "Square"}.

I am going to paste the whole code. 

var largest = 0
var largestKind: String?
for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for number in numbers {
        if number > largest {
            largest = number
            if let oldLargestKind = largestKind {
                if oldLargestKind != kind {
                    largestKind = kind
                }
            } else {
                largestKind = kind
            }
        }
    }
}
largest
largestKind

Comment: @Tomasero I updated my answer. Please note that you only have access to the actual value within the if statement.

Comment: I understand that you can access the value of largestKind using let. What I don't understand is how to extract the value of kind in "for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers"
Because when I print largestKind at the end of the code it says {Some "Square"} instead of just "Square". Thanks again for all your help

Comment: @Tomasero, yes I am saying don't print largestKind at the end. I am saying print the unwrapped value within the `if let` statement. You need to keep largestKinda as optional because it needs to start with a value and you need to handle the case that `interestingNumbers` is nil. But maybe I am misunderstanding you, if you think so, please write out in [pseudocode](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/P/pseudocode.html) what you want.